# Offscreencanvas illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm testing the new [offscreen Canvas in firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas), and I haven't any trouble with asynchronous offscreen canvas in web workers (gfx.offscreencanvas are enabled), but when I try to do the first example, I get an illegal constructor error in offscreenCanvas constructor:

```
var offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/meji/hrwp7ju4/) an example. I'm using firefox 44 on ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: It is an experimental technology so you more than likely have to activate it.  And make sure you have a supported version of fire foax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OffScreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas#Browser_compatibility) has basic support since version 44 of firefox but [offScreenCanvas constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/OffscreenCanvas#Browser_compatibility) has support since version **46** of firefox

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas#Browser_compatibility) for OffscreenCanvas. And there's a small but important piece of text:

> This feature is behind a feature preference setting. In about:config, set gfx.offscreencanvas.enabled to true

Just checked in my Firefox (44) on Ubuntu - works fine.

Comment: This preference is set to true. As I said, I can use offscreen canvas with:
`var offscreen = htmlCanvas.transferControlToOffscreen();` 
but not with:
 `new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);`